# Listas por comprensión Python

Tags: python

```
acortado=[palabra if len(palabra)<=5 else palabra[:5]+"@" for palabra in frase1]
```

Este codigo es por lista de comprensión, pero necesito ponerlo como un bucle tradicional y la verdad no entiendo mucho. Segun yo empezaria asi

```
for palabra in frase1:
```

pero no se como acomodar el resto

Comment: Lo que hace tu codigo es, si la palabra es mayor de 5 caracteres , todo lo que este después del 5yo carácter es remplazado por `@`, de lo contrario la palabra se queda igual, y eso es añadido a la lista

Comment: @christian si asi es, eso hace, pero lo quiero poner en un bucle tradicional, el problema es que no se como acomodar el palabra[:5]+"@"

Comment: Pues así como esta, no tienes que cambiar nada, con lo que te dije puedes hacer el ciclo de la forma normal

Comment: ¿Leíste mi respuesta? Creo que allí está clara la forma de hacerlo. Si tienes dudas, no dudes en dejarme un comentario (en la respuesta).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parte de derecha a izquierda:

```
acortado=[palabra if len(palabra)<=5 else palabra[:5]+"@" for palabra in frase1]
```

Primero tomamos el `for`, que es lo último:

```
for palabra in frase1:
```

El resto de la expresión produce un valor mediante un operador if-ternario

```
palabra if len(palabra)<=5 else palabra[:5]+"@"
```

que tradicionalmente se escribe asi:

```
if len(palabra)<=5: 
    palabra
else:
    palabra[:5]+"@"
```

Como veras, la instrucción está incompleta, pues sólo aparece el valor y no se dice que hacer con él. Falta agregarlo a la lista en formación:

```
resultado = []
for palabra in frase1:
    if len(palabra) <= 5: 
        resultado.append(palabra)
    else:
        resultado.append(palabra[:5]+"@")
```

Answer (score 3):

Te voy a responder con un ejemplo:

A continuación tenemos una lista de números, que van del 1 al 10.

Luego tenemos una expresión equivalente a la de la pregunta, que crea una nueva lista, trasladando de la lista original los números pares y poniendo un cero en la posición de los impares.

Luego, hace el mismo trabajo en otra nueva lista con un `for` tradicional.

```
numeros = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
paresYCeros1 = [numero if numero%2 == 0 else 0 for numero in numeros]

paresYCeros2 = []
for numero in numeros:
    if numero%2 == 0:
        paresYCeros2.append(numero)
    else: 
        paresYCeros2.append(0)
print(paresYCeros1)
print(paresYCeros2)
```

La salida es:

```
[0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0, 10]
[0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0, 10]
```

Te invito a entender el código y podrás hacer lo que buscas por ti misma.

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente lo que te está despistando es el fragmento:

```
palabra if len(palabra)<=5 else palabra[:5]+"@"
```

que no tiene nada qué ver con comprensiones de listas, sino que se trata de una *expresión ternaria*.

Una expresión en Python es algo que al ser evaluado produce un resultado, el cual se puede asignar a una variable. Por ejemplo `2+3` es una expresión que produce como resultado 5, y por tanto puede ser asignado a una variable. En cambio `while (a>3)` no es una expresión, pues no produce un resultado, sino que es una sentencia de control.

La expresión que he escrito más arriba es confusa porque aparecen en ella las palabras `if` y `else` que hacen pensar que se trate de una sentencia de control (como `while` u otras). En cambio no se trata de una sentencia de control, sino de una sintaxis especial para hacer una expresión que al ser evaluada, produce ya sea un resultado o ya sea otro.

Por ejemplo, considera la siguiente asignación:

```
x = 1 if a>0 else -1
```

Al evaluar esa expresión al final `x` tomará el valor 1 o -1. Lo que hay a la derecha del `=` es por tanto una expresión, pues produce un resultado que se puede asignar a una variable. Lo que ocurre es que el resultado de la expresión depende de la condición `a>0`. Si esa condición es cierta, la expresión tomará el valor `1` y si es falsa tomará el valor `-1`. Puedes leerlo por tanto como:

> *Asigna a `x` el valor 1 si `a` es positivo, y si no el valor -1*

Otros lenguajes de programación harían eso mismo con esta otra sintaxis:

```
x = (a>0)?1:-1
```

lo que se conoce como el operador ternario. Pero en Python el operador ternario es `valor1 if condicion else valor2`.

Por supuesto todo eso puedes hacerlo también con una estructura de control normal, que sería así para este ejemplo:

```
if a>0:
  x = 1
else:
  x = -1
```

Por tanto, tu expresión se implementaría con una estructura de control en lugar de un operador ternario así:

```
if len(palabra)<=5:
  resultado = palabra
else:
  resultado = palabra[:5]+"@"
```

Y ese resultado es el que se va añadiendo a la lista que estás construyendo, ya que una comprensión de listas tiene la forma general `[expresion for elemento in lista]`, sólo que en tu caso la `expresion` era un operador ternario como se ha explicado.

Si a lo anterior añadimos que `lista2 = [expresion for elemento in lista]` se puede convertir en un `for` normal así:

```
lista2 = []
for elemento in lista:
  lista2.append(expresion)
```

creo que ya tienes todos los ingredientes necesarios para saber "desenrollar" tu comprensión de listas con operador ternario en una estructura de control `for` con otra estructura de control `if/else` dentro.